# Python - Sum of factorials

Tags: python

I've tried to create a program that checks each number to see if it is equal to the sum of the factorials of its individual digits. For some reason that eludes me, it fails to add any values to the list, and if I were to print the summed variable after each instance, it would display summed as equal to 0. Can anyone help?

```
import math

x = 2
y = 0
summed = 0
listed = []

while x < 10000000:
        x += 1
        summed = 0
        xString = str(x)
        xLength = len(xString)
        while y < xLength:
                summed += math.factorial(int(xString[y]))
                y += 1
        if (x == summed):
                listed.append(x)

y = 0
summed = 0

listLength = len(listed)

while y < listLength:
        summed += listed[y]
        y += 1

print(listed)
print(summed)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `y = 0` inside your while loop

Comment: Aye, I saw that as soon as I posted this damn thing, thanks anyway! ^_^

Answer (score 2):

Never mind, I noticed I'd failed to reset the y value at the end of each instance.

```
y = 0
```

that's all it took.

Comment: The answers are not just for your benefit, but for the benefit of many others.  You should expect to see multiple answers to a question.

Answer (score 2):

A better way to loop over a string is like this:

```
xString = str(x)
for c in xString:
    summed += math.factorial(int(c))
```

And over the final list:

```
for item in listed:
    summed += item
```

Then you don't need `y` at all.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat simplified version:

```
import math

listed = []
for x in xrange(2, 10000000):
    summed = sum(math.factorial(int(d)) for d in str(x))
    if (x == summed): listed.append(x)
summed = sum(y for y in listed)

print(listed)
print(summed)
```

and some faster version:

```
import math

facts  = dict()
def ffact(sn):
    if len(sn) == 1: return math.factorial(int(sn))
    if sn not in facts:
        facts[sn] = ffact(sn[0])
        if len(sn) > 1: facts[sn] += ffact(sn[1:])
    return facts[sn]

listed = list()
for x in xrange(2, 1000000):
    if ffact(str(x)) == x: listed.append(x)
summed = sum(y for y in listed)

print(listed)
print(summed)
```

Answer (score 1):

(This is not posted to be an answer, but because it's hard to format code as a comment.)

```
from math import factorial as fact

def digits(n):
    return [int(d) for d in str(n)]

def isSumOfOwnDigitsFactorialed(n):
    return n==sum(fact(d) for d in digits(n))
```

Demo:

```
>>> digits(152)
[1, 5, 2]

>>> [i for i in range(10**6) if isSumOfOwnDigitsFactorialed(i)]
[1, 2, 145, 40585]
```